# Map complex legacy tables to Core 2 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvvm, asp.net-core-2.0

I am building a functional extension to a vendor's system, essentially I trying to use the entity framework with legacy tables.

The primary feature of my application is a list of drivers, their assigned vehicle, the destination, the client, and when they are scheduled to start; similar to what you'd see at an airport or train station.

One of the challenges, as it relates to EF, are the models that supports this 'view':  for regular routes there are 5 tables, for ad-hoc routes there are 8 tables.  The two models share the tables for `Vehicle` and `Driver`.

The easiest solution is to create a database view (`vwRoutes`)that performs the necessary abstractions and `UNION`s the two data sets, then populate a collection (of what exactly) using `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
  string query = @"SELECT * FROM vwRoutes WHERE...";
  var routes = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(query);
  return View(await movements.ToListAsync()); # <- incorrect
}
```

Then use the `routes` collection in the view.

Questions:

- If I use this approach, what type of collection is created by `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`?   How do I use it in a view?

The second option is to model each table (11 total), then somehow combine the results in a `ViewModel`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{

  var regular = _context.RegularRoutes;
  var adhoc = _context.AdHocRoutes;

  # use a big VM
  var RoutesViewModel = new RoutesViewModel();
  RoutesViewModel.RegularRoutes = regular;
  RoutesViewModelAdhocRoutes = adhoc;

  return View(await RoutesViewModel.ToListAsync());

  # 
  # OR 
  # 

  # map each collection to a viewmodel
  how?

}
```

Questions:

- If I use this approach, should the `ViewModel` have two collections (e.g. `RoutesViewModel.RegularRoutes`;`RoutesViewModel.AdhocRoutes`) or should I try to map it to a de-normalized `ViewModel` (see below)?  Can `AutoMapper` map the two classes to the single, de-normalized `ViewModel`?

RoutesViewModel:

```
RoutesViewModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string DriverName { get; set; }
  public string Vehicle { get; set; }
  public string Destination { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartingTime { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` returns an `int` specifying the number of rows affected, not a set.

Comment: If you want to use a view, you need to create an Entity that maps to the view, and specify the Key Properties of the Entity (the properties that uniquely identify rows in the view).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Could I add a `ROW_NUMBER()` to the view (with an alias of `ID`) and use it as the primary key for the entity?  The key wouldn't be used for insert/update/delete purposes.

Comment: It's normally simpler to just expose the key of some underlying table(s).  In the case of a UNION ALL, you might need to add a column to the view to be part of the key.  EG (RouteId, RouteType), where RouteType indicates which Route table the row came from.